# Can't define a event and bind an <a4j:support/> on this event at the same time

Tags: jsf, richfaces, ajax4jsf

Let's consider this simple code:

```
<h:form id="myForm">
    <h:inputText id="myInput">
        <a4j:support event="onchange" actionListener="#{myBean.doSomething}"/>
    </h:inputText>
</h:form>
```

this will generate the following HTML code:

```
<input id="myForm:myInput" type="text" name="myForm:myInput" onchange="A4J.AJAX.Submit(...)" />
```

Now, I just add something in the `onchange` event of my `<h:inputText>`:

```
<h:form id="myForm">
    <h:inputText id="myInput" onchange="alert('foobar');">
        <a4j:support event="onchange" actionListener="#{myBean.doSomething}"/>
    </h:inputText>
</h:form>
```

This will generate the following HTML code:

```
<input id="myForm:myInput" type="text" name="myForm:myInput" onchange="alert('foobar');" />
```

As you can see, the Ajax code is **not added** anymore. This is a really strange behavior as far as I am concerned. Why the `<a4j:support>` does not attach the Ajax call if the event is already defined in the input field?

So my question is how to make the `<a4j:support>` working on an `event` that is already defined in the `input`? Of course, the solution must run both the Javascript code defined in `onchange` **and** the Ajax call.

In others words, I would like to have the following HTML:

```
<input id="myForm:myInput" type="text" name="myForm:myInput" onchange="alert('foobar'); A4J.AJAX.Submit(...)" />
```

---

I am using Richfaces 3.3.2 and JSF 1.2

---

**EDIT**

Of course, I can move the `onchange` Javascript code in the `onsubmit` attribute of the `<a4j:support>`, doing something like that:

```
<h:inputText id="myInput">
    <a4j:support onsubmit="alert('foobar');" event="onchange" actionListener="#{myBean.doSomething}"/>
</h:inputText>
```

But is it the only way??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**More about the context**

In fact, I can't really modify the `event` value of the `<a4j:support>`, like suggesteed by [Abel Morelos](https://stackoverflow.com/users/124123/abel-morelos), because what I am trying to do is to add a custom component that execute some client-side validation. This validation calls a Javascript function, so my custom component modifies the `onchange` value of his parent.

My JSF code will looks like:

```
<h:inputText id="myInput">
    <my:validation .../>
    <a4j:support event="onchange" actionListener="#{myBean.doSomething}"/>
</h:inputText>
```

This code is quite equivalent to the following code, except that the `onchange` of the `<h:inputText>` is added automatically by my component:

```
<h:inputText id="myInput" onchange="if (!checkSomeValidation()) { return false; }">
    <a4j:support event="onchange" actionListener="#{myBean.doSomething}"/>
</h:inputText>
```

So as you can understand, my custom component directly modifies the `onchange` event of the `<h:inputText>`, and due to the problem with `<a4j:support>`, the Ajax call is **not** binded to the input component at the end.

---

**The solution**

When linked to a JSF component, the `<a4j:support>` will "transform" itself to a facet, whose name is `org.ajax4jsf.ajax.SUPPORTxxx`, where `xxx` is the `event` name. So in my case, the `<h:inputText>` will have a facet named `org.ajax4jsf.ajax.SUPPORTonchange`.

So what I do in my Java code of my custom component, is to check if the parent (the `<h:inputText>` here), has such a facet.

If **no**, it means that the parent has no `<a4j:support event="onchange"/>` linked to it. So in this case, I modify the `onchange` attribute of my `<h:inputText/>`

If **yes**, it means that there is a `<a4j:support event="onchange"/>` linked to the parent. So I modify the facet itself using the following code:

```
HtmlAjaxSupport facet = (HtmlAjaxSupport) getParent().getFacet("org.ajax4jsf.ajax.SUPPORTonchange");
if (facet != null) {
    facet.setOnsubmit("my Javascript code goes here");
} else {
    getParent().setOnchange("my Javascript goes here");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If this behaviour is not explicitly documented, I would consider this as a bug in Ajax4jsf. Report it to Ajax4jsf/RichFaces guys over there at JBoss.org. I've [seen](http://forums.sun.com/thread.jspa?threadID=5390192) problems like that before with `<a4j:commandButton onclick="someFunction()">`

Comment: I've created a thread on the Richfaces forum, at least to understand if this behavior is the expected behavior from RF team...

Answer (score 1):

I already had this problem before, and I found that RichFaces 3.3.x will execute only the code for the onchange event defined with a4j:support and will ignore the onchange code defined with the JSF component.

In my case the workaround was simple, for my case it was valid to use other event instead of "onchange" (not sure if it was onclick or onselect), so I attached my code to this other event and my code worked, but I'm not sure if this could work for you. If you really need the onchange event for both elements, you'll have to do just as BalusC said and report it to the RichFaces folks.

Comment: This is a possible solution, but in my case, it is not applicable (see my *answer* to understand why).